# PeerJS error when trying to call another peer: Failed to execute 'addStream' on 'RTCPeerConnection': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc, peerjs

I am successfully establishing a connection between two peers using PeerJS but whenever I try passing a MediaStream object to the `.call` function I get this error:

> Failed to execute 'addStream' on 'RTCPeerConnection': parameter 1 is
>   not of type 'MediaStream'

Everything else works great, connection is indeed established, both peers receive messages from each other via the `'open'` event. The only thing that doesn't work is the `peer.call()` function. The microphone is properly captured after requesting the permission to do so.

**Am I making some kind of a mistake here?** I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
var media;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var peer = new Peer({
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  });

  media = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false
  });

  peer.on('open', function(id) {
    console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
  });

  var conn = peer.connect(callID);

  conn.on('open', function() {
    // Receive messages
    conn.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('Received', data);
    });

    // Send messages
    conn.send('Hello!');
  });

  console.log(typeof(media));

  var call = peer.call(callID, media);

  peer.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be interested to see the output of `console.log(typeof(media));`.

According to the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), it seems that the following line will return a `Promise` instead of a `MediaStream`:

```
media = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});
```

The following should work:

```
var media;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var peer = new Peer({
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  });

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: false
    })
    .then(function(mediaStream) {
      peer.on('open', function(id) {
        console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
      });

      var conn = peer.connect(callID);

      conn.on('open', function() {
        // Receive messages
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log('Received', data);
        });

        // Send messages
        conn.send('Hello!');
      });

      console.log(typeof(media));

      var call = peer.call(callID, mediaStream);

      peer.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me :).